# passing data to another view controller with IBAction without segue swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, ibaction

I have got a simple app where I am wanting to pass data to another view controller with a button without segueing to it. SO basically on one view controller I have a text box where the user enters there name, when they press the submit button I want their name to pass to another view controller containing a label but without navigating to that view, staying on the view controller that has the submit button

THis is my IBAction for the button to submit the data:

```
 @IBAction func addPlant(sender: AnyObject)
 {  
 }
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're actually trying to do.  Does the other view controller already exist?  Ie., is it higher in the stack of a navigation controller or in another panel of a split view controller?

Comment: @EricD. That's not a duplicate because it's talking about passing data to a VC being opened, just not using a segue to do it.  This is about not opening a new VC at all.

Comment: @EricD. perhaps...  but there's still a lot of assumptions made there (like where creating the new view controller with `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` (and not probably not saving it away so you're not actually doing anything)  There's really just not enough info in the question to say what he's really trying to do :)

Comment: Apologises for the poor explanation, I have never been good at that, I have a main menu screen with 2 buttons, one button will navigate to a view controller where the user can input their name and submit it, the other button on the main menu will direct the user to a list of the names that have been submitted, I am needing help with passing the data from the text box on the submission page to the list on the other page without any navigation. @DavidBerry

Answer (score 0):

when the submit button was pressed, you can story the user name into where all controller can get it, such as UserDefault, SQLit.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
//where the user enters name
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *userNameTF;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

}
- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    /**
     *  story the userName into NSUserDefaults
     */
    [userDefaults setObject:self.userNameTF.text forKey:@"userName"];
    //if ios8 need:
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}

@end
```

another view controller

```
#import "OtherViewController.h"

@interface OtherViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *userNameLabel;

@end

@implementation OtherViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    //get the userName from NSUserDefaults
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    self.userNameLabel.text = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"userName"];

}



@end
```

Swift Version－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－
ViewController：

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var userNameTF: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func addPlant(sender: AnyObject) {
        let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults();
        /**
        *  story the userName into NSUserDefaults
        */
        userDefaults.setObject(userNameTF.text, forKey:"userName");
        //if iOS8 before need:
        userDefaults.synchronize();
    }



}
```

OtherViewController：

```
import UIKit

class OtherViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var userNameLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults();
        //get the userName from NSUserDefaults
        self.userNameLabel.text = userDefaults.objectForKey("userName") as? String;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, is there a swift version please?

Comment: thank you, how would I populate a tableviewcell using userDefaults?

Answer (score 0):

you could use delegates to achieve this.

are you using swift or objective-c ?

the general steps to create delegates are

1. Create a delegation protocol (defines what the View wants the Controller to take care of)
2. Create a delegate property in the View whose type is that delegation protocol
3. Use the delegate property in the View to get/do things it can’t own or control
4. Controller declares that it implements the protocol
5. Controller sets self as the delegate of the View by setting the property in #2 above
6. Implement the protocol in the Controller